# WCF Duplex Contract

Tags: c#, wcf, duplex

Say I have WCF service contract like this

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ICallback1),
SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IService1
{
  // some methods
}
```

The service implementation has `InstanceContextMode.Single` set for `InstanceContextMode`
and `ICallback1` is something like

```
public interface ICallback1
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Report(int someValue);
}
```

Now on client side, I can have a class the implements ICallback1 like

```
class Callback1 : ICallback1
{
    public void Report(int someValue)
    {
        // alert client
    }
}
```

and I create client service reference like this

```
Service1Client serviceClient = new Service1Client(new InstanceContext(new CallBack1()));
```

which works fine. Now the problem is that I have some clients that are not interested in the callback so I figured I do not require to implement the callback interface for such clients so I tried this

```
 Service1Client serviceClient = new Service1Client(null);
```

and

```
 Service1Client serviceClient = new Service1Client(new InstanceContext(null));
```

both reported that the `parameter cannot be null`. My question is, how can i create a service reference without passing a callback object if the client is not interested in the callback. The only requirement is that all clients should be talking to the same service but otherwise I can restructure the service however. Any thoughts ?

EDIT:

I have also tried  `SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed` for ServiceContract instead of `SessionMode.Required` but that didn't help either.

Comment: It looks impossible as long as it is part of contract.

Comment: Can the CallbackContract be optional?

Comment: In simple terms, Callback is defined as a part of Service Contract, this is constant. Configuring everything else doesnt change the contract, so it looks impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround: Remove the CallbackContract from IService1. Create IDuplexService1 which inherits IService1 and contains the CallbackContract. Have Service1Client implement IDuplexService1. When instantiating the host, call `ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint` for both IService1 and IDuplexService1.